# Resize parent UIView based on its children size

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, centering

I'm new in iOS programming and still don't know how to handle correctly basic stuff like this so I hope someone has good practice to share.

I created a custom keyboard for the user to answer to a question.
It's an UIView containing some UIButton.

[image]

How does one center the whole keyboard?

I know I could calculate the width of the keyboard by adding up the width of each key but this seems quite complicated for such a simple action.

Here's my code (in Swift) for now, thanks.

```
keyboardContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, 200))
keyboardContainer!.center = CGPoint(x: keyboardContainer!.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height - keyboardContainer!.frame.height / 2)
self.addSubview(keyboardContainer!)

let gap = Int(self.frame.width) / 8

for i in 0..<keyboardLetters!.count {
    let posX = Int(i % 7) * gap + 22
    let posY = Int(i / 7) * gap + 25

    let key = Key(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
    key.letter = keyboardLetters![i]
    key.tag = i
    key.center = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY)
    keyboardContainer!.addSubview(key)

    key.addTarget(self, action: "onKeyboardTap:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the center of `keyboardContainer` and all the buttons will move with it.

Comment: I updated my question with the code where I create keyboardContainer, it's already centered.

Comment: If it's just the black column you are worried about, that's because you assume 8 columns in part of the code and only 7 in other parts.